# What does it mean to be "a spectator of the human world"?

Tags: interpretation

> Anthony was nineteen when I met him, a shy young
>   man who found computers reassuring. He felt insecure in the world of people
>   with its emotional risks and shades of gray. The activity and interactivity of
>   computer programming gave Anthony-lonely, yet afraid of intimacy-the feeling
>   that he was not alone.s In Love and Sex, Levy idealizes Anthony's accommodation
>   and suggests that loving a robot would be a reasonable next step for
>   people like him. I was sent an advance copy of the book, and Levy asked if I
>   could get a copy to Anthony, thinking he would be flattered. I was less sure. I
>   didn't remember Anthony as being at peace with his retreat to what he called
>   "the machine world:" I remembered him as wistful, **feeling himself a spectator
>   of the human world**, like a kid with his nose to the window of a candy store.
>   When we imagine robots as our future companions, we all put our noses to that
>   same window.

I'm particularly confused about this:

> I remembered him as wistful, feeling himself a spectator
>   of the human world, like a kid with his nose to the window of a candy store.
>   When we imagine robots as our future companions, we all put our noses to that
>   same window.

Anothony certainly feels lonely, but afraid of dealing with other people. He finds out that computers make him feel that someone is there. I guess maybe the author is trying to say that Anothony actually longs to make friends with other people when she says "feeling himself a spectator of the human world"?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Anthony feels unable to fully (or freely) participate in the "human world."

Comment: "like a kid with his nose to the winddow of a candy store" Does that mean that Anthony though socially inept, is longing for a relationship with real people rather than with mechines?

Answer (score 1):

In this context "feeling himself a spectator of the human world" implies that Anthony feels like an outsider - like the world of people happens right in front of his eyes, but he is unable to participate. The following passage - "like a kid with his nose to the window of a candy store" - can mean several things: that Anthony actually wants to partake in the world of people, that he feels sad that he cannot do that, or both. In both cases, the important topic is separation - the "window" in this case - that allows you to look in from the outside, but you're still on the outside by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A person can feel like an outsider looking in, like someone who wants to be more involved, but isn't. Sports metaphors are often used to describe this feeling, such as:

> I feel like I was ***on the bench*** instead of ***in the game***.
>
> I felt like I was ***on the sidelines*** instead of doing what I wanted to be doing.

In the passage you quote, the author uses two metaphors to describe this feeling. In the first, the character is described as a spectator instead of a participant, as though humans are somehow engaged in a huge football match, and the character is watching from the stands. (Although the stands might be a fun place to be if you were watching, say, Manchester vs Liverpool, that's not the image this metaphor strives to paint. Instead, the metaphor is followed up by *like a kid with his nose to the window of a candy store*, where, once again, someone is ***on the outside looking in***, of merely observing instead of fully participating, all the while wanting to be more involved.)